# How to change text in JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

In **JFileChooser** Java swing component I need to change all text elements (for translation):

*File name:* (JLabel)

*Files of type:* (JLabel)

*Cancel* (JButton)

Unfortunately, it is not any methods for that..

Is there any way I can do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The Swing components in Java are fully able to understand internationalization. [This article](http://beradrian.wordpress.com/2007/07/30/internationalization-for-swing-standard-components/) explains the details and shows an example of how it can be accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIManager.put("FileChooser.fileNameLabelText", "FileName");
UIManager.put("FileChooser.filesOfTypeLabelText", "TypeFiles");
```

Answer (score 2):

The `showDialog()` is used to display a custom dialog (e.g. not an Open nor Save dialog). It has a parameter to specify the text of the Approve button. If the title has not been set with the `setDialogTitle()` method, the implementation arbitrarily chooses to use the approve button's text as the title on Windows OS, however this is not documented anywhere and you should not count on this to work.

If you want a custom title, use `setDialogTitle()`. If you want a custom approve button text, use `setApproveButtonText()`. Obviously `showDialog()` also takes the approve button's text in which case you do not need to call `setApproveButtonText()` prior.

If you want an Open dialog, use the `showOpenDialog()` method. If you want a Save dialog, use the `showSaveDialog()`. Only use `showDialog()` if you want a custom dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Use UIManager

```
    UIManager.put("FileChooser.saveButtonText","Custom text acept");
    UIManager.put("FileChooser.cancelButtonText","custom text to cancel");
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to translate `JFileChooser` text, I would suggest you change `JFileChooser` locale (by calling [`JFileChooser#setLocale(Locale)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocale%28java.util.Locale%29)) instead of hacking you way into `JFileChooser` its internals. Indeed, all `JFileChooser` texts are locale dependant. As a consequence, changing locale to be the one you want will alter these texts with less efforts.

Comment: That only works if `JFileChooser` has genuine support for the particular language. Prior to JDK 11, this was limited to English, Japanese, Chinese, French, German, Italian, Korean, Portuguese (Brazilian), Spanish, and Swedish. Starting with JDK 11, Oracle decided to drop most languages (for no apparent reason). So now, this only works for English, Japanese, and Chinese. But generally, any JRE may support an arbitrary set of languages and you don’t even have a way to find out, which are currently supported…

Answer (score 0):

Normally `JFileChooser@setLocale(Locale)` works as Riduidel says. On Mac OSX though this is ignored.

On Mac OSX to correctly set the default locale you call `UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().setDefaultLocale(Locale);`
Note that this only works for Java 8 and not for Java 7!

It seems that even though for every other Look and Feel you use `UIManager.getDefaults().setDefaultLocale(Locale);`
for the Aqua look and feel this doesn't work. It looks like in `AquaFileChooserUI.java` in the method `protected void installStrings(JFileChooser paramJFileChooser)` the calls to `UIManager.getString()` do not use the locale whereas other installStrings() methods, for example in BasicFileChooserUI,
do use the locale in the `protected void installStrings(JFileChooser)`
method.

Aqua:  `UIManager.getString("FileChooser.cancelButtonText");`

Basic: `UIManager.getString("FileChooser.cancelButtonText",l);`

`fileChooser.setLocale(Locale);` is still ignored on OSX though.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a modified version of one posted by Fasimba/Icewalker on [the DevX Java forum](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?98648-JFileChooser-caption-for-quot-Cancel-quot-button). <sup>1</sup> I have quoted his answer, only modifying the search and replace parameters. I **do not** take credit for the logic expressed in it.

```
public void changeButtonText (Component c, String original, String change) {

   if (c instanceof JButton) {
       JButton b = (JButton) c;
       if (b.getText() != null && b.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(original))
           b.setText(change);
   } else if (c instanceof Container) {
        Container cont = (Container) c;
        for (int i = 0; i < cont.getComponents().length; i++) {
           changeButtonText (cont.getComponent(i), original, change);
        }
   }
}
```

Call it as follows:

```
// dirChooser is the JFileChooser instance
for (Component c : dirChooser.getComponents()) changeButtonText(c, "Cancel", "Don't do it!");
```

---

1. Posted to [the DevX Java forum](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?98648-JFileChooser-caption-for-quot-Cancel-quot-button) on 23/06/2004, 08:06 AM